# Exporting an enum class from a module by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have declared an enum class within my class as below.

module xx

```
class X(object):
    class my_enum(Enum):
        a = 1
        b = 2

    def test (self, p1=my_enum.a):
        print(p1)
```

my module:

```
from xx import X
o = X(X.my_enum.a)
```

The problem is that the pycharm tool-tip says `self, p1=my_enum.a`

When I write as below to get a correct tool-tip it gives an unresolved reference error for LabelledUI.X.p1:

module xx

```
class X(object):
    class my_enum(Enum):
        a = 1
        b = 2

    def test (self, X.p1=my_enum.a):
        print(p1)
```

Now I can create the enum class out of contained class but that will require an extra import statement which I am trying to avoid to reduce user effort.

module xx

```
class my_enum(Enum):
        a = 1
        b = 2


class X(object):
    def test (self, X.p1=my_enum.a):
        print(p1)
```

my module:

```
from xx import X, my_enum
o = X(X.my_enum.a)
```

Any suggestions how I can create it in such a way that the user tool-tip reads the correct enum class without the user having to add an extra import statement?

Is there any way I can export this enum by default without the user having to do an `from xx import *`

Comment: I would request the person down voting to also provide the reason for down vote. I don't think the question deserves a down vote without reason.

Comment: Actually I don't understand, what you are trying to achieve. A nested class has the main purpose, to restrict the scope to within the outer class. That your xx module needs to pass an inner class seems to contradict that purpose.

Comment: The downvote might have been caused by the inconsistency of your code examples. You define a class named (capital) `X` with a method named `test`. In your `module` you import and instantiate a class named (lower case) `x` from your module, you don't use the `test`method at all but instantiate the class with the arguments you would use when calling `test`. Makes it hard to grasp what you are up to; although I agree that a downvote deserves an explanation.

Comment: @guidot - No it does not need to be nested inside - that's only because I need that to be imported along with the container class and what you have highlighted is also something I am trying to overcome. So what you didn't like about this implementation is the issue I am trying to overcome. I see from this that we are concerned about the same issue.

Comment: Ok @shmee I have corrected that - thanks for pointing out

Comment: @barry_allen: In that case I would not nest it. Depending on the number of additional importable things in that module, setting the `__all__` attribute of the module may be a solution, but I dont see, what is wrong with simply mentioning both classes in the import: Actually I strive towards this kind of explicitness.

Comment: I agree with @guidot. If you need external code to pass a member of that enum class into your instances of `X`, then this is not the place for 'hiding' `my_enum`. If you really, _really_, **really** don't want to import `my_enum` explicitly and also not use star imports, you could create a staticmethod on `X` that returns `my_enum`. Then you can just import `X` and do `o = X().test(X.get_enum().a)` to call your `test` method. But that's not gonna win any beauty contests ...

Comment: Its about ease of usability, the user should be least bothered to import. But I guess that is not possible here. The hidden class does give the advantage, even if it is not a purist's implementation, that user doesn't need to import anything else. I am new to python and I am not aware of the ```__all__``` keyword so I will look it up.

Comment: Ok so using ```__all__``` does solve it a bit but loading a lot of module was advised to be avoided by people reviewing my code so I pehaps would still think a bit more on the implementation.

Comment: Do you need `my_enum` outside your module `xx.py` for anything else than to pass it as argument to callables inside `xx.py`? If not, there's also the option to let users of your module pass in the name of the enum member and do the lookup internally. In this case the user does not need to know about the enum and thus does not need to import it: `def test(self, p1='a'): print(self.my_enum[p1])`. This will raise a `KeyError` if a non-existent member name is given.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid - I want tooltip to display - not possible I guess without the import statement or internal class

Comment: In that case you absolutely should have users import `my_enum` explicitly. What good is it to have that enum and make people actively use it, while at the same time trying to make it fly below the radar? This will lead to confusion, not ease of use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177771/discussion-between-barry-allen-and-shmee).